# How do I run Azure CLI commands in elevated mode

Tags: .net, azure, powershell

I am trying to run the command, `'dotnet workload restore'` in an Azure Powershell and I keep getting "Inadequate permissions. Run the command with elevated privileges."

How do I run the command with `elevated privileges`?

Comment: You need to do either one or both 1) Run PS by right click shortcut and select Run As Admin 2) Change permissions on server : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 0):

> How do I run Azure CLI commands in elevated mode

I do agree with @jdweng, That if you want to run Commands in Elevated mode you need to run as administrator and it will work as mine got.

[image]

Then run:

```
dotnet workload restore
```

[image]

If this doesn't work you need to add role assignment to that user.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, however I may not have described the problem properly. I am trying to the run the commands from the azure portal (I.e. on the web). There is an icon that runs a power shell but there is no option to run in elevated mode.